# MongoDB concat two fields using aggregation where actual field is in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo document like below;

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "info" : {
        "batch" : "Batch1-Minor"
    },
    "batchElements" : {
        "elements" : [ 
             {
               "_id" : "elementId1",
               "type": "ABC"
             },  
             {
                "_id" : "elementId2",
                "type": "ABC"
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can generate an aggregated output by changing the `_id` field inside `elements` by concatenating `$info.batch` and `$batchElements.elements._id`

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "info" : {
        "batch" : "Batch1-Minor"
    },
    "batchElements" : {
        "elements" : [ 
             {
               "_id" : "Batch1-Minor-elementId1",
               "type": "ABC"
             },  
             {
                "_id" : "Batch1-Minor-elementId2",
                "type": "ABC"
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Aggregation queries can't write back to same collection, their main purpose if for querying not updating back, though there are two stages `$out` -- will overwrite the collection if existing or create a new & `$merge` - will write to new collection or create new (These two are not what we're looking at), So it has to be a normal update process, What is mongoDB version ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I don't want to update the existing collection. How can i write an aggregation stage (mostly addFields) to generate the output. I will edit the original question with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With below query we're iterating through `batchElements.elements` & forming objects with `type` & `_id` & finally `$map` would push an array of objects back to `batchElements.elements` where `$addFields` would add the field to actual document, Try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        'batchElements.elements': {
            $map:
            {
                input: "$batchElements.elements",
                as: "each",
                in: { type: '$$each.type', '_id': { $concat: ["$info.batch", "-", "$$each._id"] } }
               /** So if you've multiple fields in each object then instead of listing all, You need to use 
                in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$each", { '_id': { $concat: ["$info.batch", "-", "$$each._id"] } }] } */
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: There can be many fields inside 'batchElements.elements' other than _id and type. Is there a way to avoid mentioning all of them inside 'in' clause?

Comment: @Boat : Yeah I suspected that, you can try updated query :-)